# Time efficient integer comparison method

Tags: java, time, comparison

I am stuck with one specific part of the code where time is wasted whilst comparing for the largest PathCost and passing it to the oldPathCost. Here is a sample of the code which is forever taking sometime. The stationNames is of TreeMap type. Do suggest one other way where time could be eliminated in the running of the following code, thanks geeks!

```
for(int i=1; i<stationNames.size(); i++)
       {
           for(int j=1; j<stationNames.size() && i != j; j++)
           {
               pathCost = runQ1_Q2(i, j);
               if(pathCost > oldPathCost)
               {
                   oldPathCost = pathCost;
                   tempi = i;
                   tempj = j;
               }
           }
       }
```

And here is the runQ1_Q2 method as follows even after optimization.

```
public int runQ1_Q2(int st, int fin) throws Exception   
   {        
       graph G= new graph (edges);    
       return (G.shortestPaths(st,fin)).size();
   }
```

Comment: There aren't any major optimization opportunities in the code you've given us.  If this can be optimized at all, it probably has to do with `runQ1_Q2` or changing the algorithm entirely.

Comment: Thank you and allow me to optimize it then, @gknicker and Louis Wasserman.

Comment: @Jason, I would update you as well thanks much! :)

Comment: pass in oldPathCost to runQ1_Q2 and change runQ1_Q2 to quit as soon as you realize that pathCost will be less than oldPathCost

Comment: Move the graph G= new graph (edges); out of the runQ1_Q2. Create the graph just once and pass reference to the graph into the runQ1_Q2

Comment: @StainslavL Thanks and it works but still there is some lagginess been caused. How do I resolve it?